# To replace % marks but not \% in Perl Regex

Tags: sed, perl

I am thinking how you can replace `[^\]%` marks but not `\%` marks in the sed -command of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247003/13173). 
I think look-behind is not necessary.

My current Sed command but I think Perl is a must here

```
cat something | sed 's#%.*</#</#'
```

which removes also everything after the `%` sign i.e. all comments in LaTeX but not percentage values.

My unsuccessful Perl attempt

```
cat something | perl 's#[^\]%.*</#</#'
```

where I do not know how I make Perl to take the standard output of cat.

Data

```
------------------------------
Protocol of pre-eclampsia
------------------------------
Monitoring in 90\% cases

Antihypertensives when % this is a comment, please, remove me!
$SBP/DBP > 160/110$; slowly.     
------------------------------
```

Desired output

```
------------------------------
Protocol of pre-eclampsia
------------------------------
Monitoring in 90\% cases

Antihypertensives when
$SBP/DBP > 160/110$; slowly.     
------------------------------
```

How can you replace `%` signs but not `\%`? 
If you can do this by Sed, please, comment.

Comment: Please include an example of your input and your desired output. What should be done with `\%%%%%%%%`? How does `<` come into it?

Comment: I added an example input and output. `\%%%%%...` is a comment so everything after second % should be removed.

Comment: @terdon It should be replaced by `\%`, that's what TeX does.  However, things like `\\%` and `\\\%` are more problematic.

Comment: @lcd047 I was asking because the OP's code would replace a `%.*<` with `#<` and I wasn't sure if he wanted comments removed or true replacement of all matching characters. I still don't know why there's s `<` in the code.

Comment: @Masi do you wan to replace or remove the characters? Your code shows that you want to replace with a `>/` but your desired output just shows the comments removed. Also, again, why the `>`?

Comment: @terdon Remove characters i.e. comments, but not `\%`. This command is a part of parsing incomplete LaTeX to HTML and to Pandoc, here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247003/13173 so therefore the `<` signs.

Comment: I still don't understand. Please show us an example that matches your question. One where the `>` exists and is dealt with.

Comment: If this is about TeX comments pleas note that the behaviour of whitespace added when replacing % with a newline could pose a problem

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can you explain your comment more as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many, if not most, text parsing tools, `perl` can take input from the command line, there's no need for `cat`. You just need `-e` which lets you pass a script as a command line parameter and `-n` which means "run the script on each line of input". ALternatively, you can use the `-p` switch which means "run the script on each line of input, then print that line". These two commands are equivalent (but the second is a classic useless use of cat, use the first) :

```
perl -pe 's/foo/bar/' file
cat file | perl -pe 's/foo/bar/'
```

Now, if I understand correctly, you want to delete all LaTeX comments (though that's not what your question states). If so, a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is the easiest way:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)%.*//' file
```

Your regex should also work, you just need to keep the character you matched before the `%` and escape the backslash:

```
perl -pe 's/(^|[^\\]+)%.*/$1/' file
```

You can do the same thing with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(^|[^\\])%.*/\1/' file
```

Comment: This replaces all % signs with #, while it should just delete comment signs (`%`) and leave `\%` signs alone.

Comment: @Masi OK, see update. But please edit your question and clarify what you need.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/([^\\]*)%.*/$1/' test.tex` gives `... Monitoring in 90\ Antihypertensives when ...` so no percent sign. My Perl version is 5.18.2.

Comment: @Masi well, yes, that's what you asked for. That's what you show in your desired output, so that's what I gave you.

Comment: Desired output is updated in the body, sorry for confusion. It should be `Monitoring in 90\% cases` by just removing the `delete me` comment.

Comment: @Masi OK, see updated version.

Comment: You are right! Your command works in the given environment. I have to think this through in a larger environment which takes time, and at the moment, I do not understand why it does not work there. I let you know when I understand this better.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to replace what follows `%` but not what follows `\%`, in Perl, the easiest way is with a [negative lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f%3c!pattern)): match `%.*` only if it isn't preceded by a backslash.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)%.*//'
```

However this won't match something like `Hello world.\\%wibble`. For that, you need to check that the `%` is preceded by an even number of backslashes. You can't do that with a lookbehind, because Perl's lookbehinds only support fixed-length patterns. Instead, match the backslashes in the regexp, and use a lookbehind to ensure that the regexp captures them all.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)%.*/$1/'
```

You can do that with tools that don't support lookbehind as well. In this case, you'll need to either use a tricky succession of replacement commands or match the backslashes and copy them to the replacement text.

```
sed -e 's/^\(\(\\\\\)*\)%.*/\1/' -e 's/\([^\\]\(\\\\\)*\)%.*/\1/'
```

Note that if you're processing a LaTeX document, there are other percent signs that might need to stay, for example in verbatim blocks. That can't be done with regexps alone.

Comment: Is there a wobble in your wibble in the `sed` version? I don't get the expected results. If I uderstand it correctly, it is intended to delete *zero to all* prefixed '\\' pairs + `%` + *`the rest of the line`* such as in the lines –
    `%wibble x0`,
    `\\%wibble x2`,
    `\\\\%wibble x4`,
    `x0 \\%wbble`,
    `x2 \\%wbble`,
    `x4 \\\\%wobble`.  If that is so, then I believe this works: `sed -e 's/^\(\\\\\)*%.*//' -e 's/\([^\\]\)\(\\\\\)*%.*/\1/'`

Comment: @Peter.O Oops, yes, both the perl and the sed versions were missing some bits. Your sed version removes backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom to replace unescaped characters in `perl` is with:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '% \% \\% \\\%' | perl -pe 's/(\\.)|%/$1||"<replacement>"/ge'
<replacement> \% \\<replacement> \\\%
```

So to remove everything starting from an unescaped `%`:

```
perl -pe 's/(\\.)|%.*/$1/g'
```

If your `sed` supports `-E` (FreeBSD/GNU):

```
sed -E 's/(\\.)|%.*/\1/g'
```

Or with GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(\\.\)\|%.*/\1/g'
```

Where the alternation RE operator is not available (as in standard basic RE), you could often use `\{0,1\}` instead:

```
sed 's/\(\(\(\\.\)\{0,1\}[^\\%]*\)*\)\(%.*\)\{0,1\}/\1/'
```